# foreach loop to only echo results that are greater than 0

Tags: php

I have a list of text fields and next to them a drop down for each text field.

The text field is an employee name and the drop down is numbers 1-8.

The default of the dropdown is 0.

I want to insert the name and number into the database only where the number is greater than 0 as I don't need to store and employee who has a 0 number of hours worked.

I tried something like this but no joy:

```
foreach($_POST['ot_hours'] as $hours) {

            if($hours > 1) {

                foreach($_POST['employee_id'] as $employee) {

                echo $employee . " " . $hours;
                }
            }
        }
```

Before even trying to insert into a database I am just trying to echo out the results. I only selected hours for 2 employees yet I got this..

61 424 464 413 417 475 477 480 442 454 431 483 421 436 467 478 429 435 415 420 432 456 451 419 447 458 479 434 463 433 449 441 460 465 428 474 414 446 482 440 426 427 439 443 462 445 418 453 455 468 481 425 430 416 422 438 471 452 423 450 444 469 437 470 466 459 472 473 448 476 461 824 864 813 817 875 877 880 842 854 831 883 821 836 867 878 829 835 815 820 832 856 851 819 847 858 879 834 863 833 849 841 860 865 828 874 814 846 882 840 826 827 839 843 862 845 818 853 855 868 881 825 830 816 822 838 871 852 823 850 844 869 837 870 866 859 872 873 848 876 8

Which is clearly incorrect.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" tabindex="1" name="ot_hours[]">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
            </select>
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="employee" value="{$last_name}, {$first_name}" disabled>
    <input type="hidden" name="employee_id[]" value="{$id}">
</div>
```

Comment: What does print_r($_POST['ot_hours']) display, and in this scenario you really should have the employee foreach be the outter

Comment: Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] => 0 [11] => 0 [12] => 0 [13] => 0 [14] => 0 [15] => 0 , plus a whole lot more

Comment: you have to understand what "selected" means. check the incoming data.

Comment: @j08691, that gives me a parse error in my code editor.

Comment: We probably need to see the HTML for this form to be able to help with this

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^ This

Comment: @RiggsFolly, have added the hours html to my original question, will add the other now...

Comment: Odd, my parenthesis got stripped out. Let me try again. `if((int)$hours > 1) {`

Comment: And you have More than One of these sets on a page?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, it generates as many sets as there are employees e.g.: 70 sets

Comment: @j08691, that still gives me a zillion results like this: Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] =............

Comment: Do you really need a nested loop? `foreach($_POST['ot_hours'] as $i => $hours) { if ($hours > 0) echo $_POST['employee_id'][$i]." ".$hours."\n"; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so you need to control the loop with the one of the arrays but also capture its index to use on the other.

```
foreach($_POST['employee_id'] as $idx => $employee) {
    if($_POST['ot_hours'][$idx] > 1) {
        echo $employee . " " . $_POST['ot_hours'][$idx] . '<br>';
    }
}
```